# Floating icon is vertical aligned properly in jsfiddle but not in local browser

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down box with text and an inverted triangle on the right end. 
I am seeing a problem on  my local browsers, both firefox & chrome where the triangle is aligned towards the top. It looks like,

[image]

I am not seeing such a problem when i run the code on jsfiddle. Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/F3KyK/666/)..

[image]

I am using `line-height` property to align vertically as,

```
.fa-caret-down{       
   line-height: 40px;
 }

  .btn-text{
    line-height: 40px;
  }
```

Why does my local browsers behave differently? And is there a way i can move the icon to middle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't default font `line-height` overriding your `40px` one? Try `line-height: 40px !important;` and check result. If not, post screenshot from inspector with this dropdown properties shown.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your local browser doesn't show the right design. Inside my firefox 45.0.2 everything is fine.

Are you shure, that your code is equals?

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.css">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{
   background-color: #e3e4e5;
 }
 .drp-down-btn{
   margin: 20px;
   height: 40px;
   background-color: #fff;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 4px;
   width: 150px;
 }
.fa-caret-down{       
   line-height: 40px;
 }

  .btn-text{
    line-height: 40px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="drp-down-btn">
  <span class="btn-text"> My caption</span>
  <i class="fa fa-lg fa-caret-down" style="vertical-align:baseline;float:right;"></i>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```